# Powershell translation to python what is variable -bAnd math function?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to translate something from Powershell to Python, but I dont understand the powershell.

```
($UACPropertyFlags.Length) | Where-Object {$UAC -bAnd [math]::Pow(2,$_)} | ForEach-Object {If ($Attributes.Length -EQ 0) {$Attributes = $UACPropertyFlags[$_]} Else {$Attributes = $Attributes + " | " + $UACPropertyFlags[$_]}}
Return $Attributes
```

What is **{$UAC -bAnd [math]::Pow(2,$_)}**?
UAC is the int passed into the function -bAnd does ??? and [math]::pow raises 2 to the length of the UACPropertyFlagsLength? 2^32?

What is **{$UAC -bAnd [math]::Pow(2,$_)}**?

Original powershell came from http://woshub.com/decoding-ad-useraccountcontrol-value/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly, `-band` is the binary or bitwise AND operator.

`$UACPropertyFlags.Length` is the number of characters in the string property, or possibly the count of elements in that collection. The `$_` is going to be the same value. `[math]::Pow(2,$_)` is 2 raised to the power `$_`.

`$UAC -bAnd [math]::Pow(2,$_)` is therefore likely to be the value of a particular (probably the most significant) bit for the numeric value of `$UAC`. It will either be some non-zero number (true) or 0 (false).

It's a simple dynamic bitmask test.

Comment: binary And... bAnd... it makes so much sense looking at it now

Comment: @brandenwagner Yup. You can find more information at `Get-Help about_Operators`. PowerShell has a fair bit of introspection and help, but like Python you have to know where to find it!